# iOS 6 animate size of view and have constraints move other views

Tags: ios, ios6, core-animation, autolayout

I'm playing with iOS 6 autolayout for the first time and I'm trying to figure out how to mix autolayout and animation.

I've got container view, ViewA, which is a certain height. I've got a UIDatePicker, ViewB, which is 216 tall and has a constraint that sets the vertical space between ViewA and ViewB = 0, so that ViewB is essentially pinned to the bottom of ViewA.

[image]

I want to animate ViewA's height to make it smaller and have ViewB remain pegged to the bottom of ViewA the entire time.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    CGRect containerFrame = self.tableContainerView.frame;
    containerFrame.size.height -= self.datePicker.frame.size.height;
    self.tableContainerView.frame = containerFrame;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"Done");
}];
```

ViewA, the container view, does get shorter as intended, but ViewB does not follow along.

How can I get the constraints between ViewA and ViewB to automatically adjust ViewB's position during the animation?

Comment: You might find the discussion useful in my book about animation and autolayout. Basically they conflict with each other - in my view, this is a huge downside of autolayout. It's as if the autolayout people forgot to consult the animation people when iOS 6 was created. Here's the link to that section of the book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_animation_and_autolayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like from your constraints, that it should work. The problem might be the way you do the animation. You should do that with constraints, not frames. If viewA has a constraint to the bottom of the superview, then you can just animate the constant of that constraint. Make an IBOutlet to that bottom constraint, and do this (bottomCon is the outlet in my example):

```
self.bottomCon.constant = self.datePicker.bounds.size.height;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    [self.view layoutSubviews];
    [self.containerView layoutSubviews]; 
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"Done");
}];
```

In my edit, I also added the [self.containerView layoutSubviews] line. This is necessary so that its subviews are updated properly too (otherwise they just jump to the new location).

Comment: ViewA doesn't have a height constraint. How should I do this? ViewA has a Top Space constraint=Superview and a Bottom Space constraint=Superview so that it is flexible for 3.5" and 4" devices.

Comment: @KennyWyland, I thought it had a bottom constraint to the date picker not the superview. Is the picker off screen to the bottom?

Comment: @KennyWyland, I've edited my answer based on your comment. This should shorten the view by the height of the date picker.

Comment: ViewA fills the superview to start and, yes, ViewB is off of the screen at the bottom. ViewA, should initially fill the superview, but when I want to animate the datePicker, ViewB, onto the screen, I want to shorten ViewA to make room for it.

Comment: ViewB is connected to the bottom of ViewA, but ViewA isn't connected to the top of B.

Comment: @KennyWyland, that's not possible -- that's a mutual constraint, they're connected to each other.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it appears to have two constraints. It has a Bottom Space to: Superview as well as a Bottom Space to: Date Picker. I'm thinking that what I'll need to do here is remove the Bottom Space to: Superview constraint and replace it with a constant Height constraint, then update that constraint during either awakeFromNib or viewDidLoad so that it matches the phone size height. Then I can animate that constraint as you suggested.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29460/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-kenny-wyland)

Comment: Fantastic, that worked. I promoted the Bottom Space to: Superview to a User Constraint, made that an IBOutlet and then when I need to display the datePicker, used your code to change and animate the constraint.